# Solving underfull and overfull warnings

Tags: tables

Always when I want to prepare a document with LaTeX I receive different warnings including underfull and overfull but I don't know how I can handle these warnings. As you can see here i have two tables in LaTeX but I got the same errors for these, please help me how I can change these tables to solve these warnings.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
  \caption{Contention window size updating}
  \label{tab:table1}
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{3.7cm}{ll}
  \hline
\bfseries Status & \bfseries CW range \\
\hline\hline
011 & \\
101 & ${CW}_{min}$\\
111 & \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}





\begin{table}[h]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
  \caption{The simulation parameters}
  \label{tab:table2}
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{7cm}{ll}
  \hline
 \bfseries Simulation Parameter & \bfseries Value \\
\hline\hline
 Traffic type & CBR\\
CBR packet size & 512 byte\\
CBR data rate & 4 packet/s\\
Transport protocol & UDP\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using `tabularx` without `X` columns? A simple `\begin{tabular}{ll}` should be sufficient:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
  \caption{Contention window size updating}
  \label{tab:table1}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
  \hline
\bfseries Status & \bfseries CW range \\
\hline\hline
011 & \\
101 & ${CW}_{min}$\\
111 & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
  \caption{The simulation parameters}
  \label{tab:table2}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
  \hline
 \bfseries Simulation Parameter & \bfseries Value \\
\hline\hline
 Traffic type & CBR\\
CBR packet size & 512 byte\\
CBR data rate & 4 packet/s\\
Transport protocol & UDP\\
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]